# Symfony 2 don't create any cookies until a user accepts the terms

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement a way to stop Symfony 2 creating a cookie.
When a user logs onto the clients site a popup will appear which will allow the user to accept the cookie policy.
Only after this has been accepted should cookies be created.
How do I stop symfony creating cookies until this has happened?

Comment: You dont. You add the fact you are using cookies and what you use them for to your privacy policy which people should read before loging in

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly the clients has requested this functionality.

Comment: I'm guessing someone has just had the *GDPR* meeting? Legally it's absolutely fine to set **essential** cookies without asking permission (you can detail them in the cookie policy) - it's things like Analytics you need to obtain prior consent for.

Comment: Just for reference, as far as I am aware, the cookie consent part is only required for persistent cookies rather than session based cookies. I'm not sure if this helps but just trying to provide some context

Comment: @JezEmery - it's not really about persistence, it's about what the cookie is used for... if it's necessary for the site to function (e.g. maintaining the session) you're fine. *Generally* these are going to be session cookies - but there are odd cases where a persistent cookie can be OK too; for instance a persistent cookie that remembers your cookie preferences. Whereas a purely analytical cookie, even if it exists only for the session, would require prior consent.

Comment: @CD001 Where did you find this out? would it be possible to get some links?

Comment: @tomBannister - just had to go through it at work with the ICO; technically it's cookies and similar technologies: https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1545/cookies_guidance.pdf (slightly older PDF covering the PECR - but the changes for GDPR with regards to cookies aren't massive). Also: https://www.eugdpr.org/

Comment: @CD001Thanks I will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to check user upon login.

One option is to have `kernel.event_listener`

It should be something like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

/**
 * This listener ensure that logged user must accept latest terms of service
 *
 * @author po_taka
 */
class TermsForceListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof YOUR_CLASS_HERE) {
            return;
        }

        if ($user->getTermsAccepted()) {
            // terms are accepted, continue with the page loading
            return;
        }

        if (YOUR_VALIDATION_IF_CURRENT_PAGE_IS_TERMS_ACEEPTING_PAGE) {
            $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse(TERMS_ACCEPTING_PAGE, 302);
            $event->setResponse($response);
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

You can register it using the following yaml

```
YOUR_SEVICE_NAME_HERE:
    class: TermsForceListener
    arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request }
```

You can read more about symfony events here - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html